# Python program hangs after "Debugger is Active"

Tags: python, freeze

I am running `app.py` from the following Github repository: `https://github.com/fu-malaria/fu-malaria`. The file can be found in the `flask` folder. When I run it, the program prints the following and hangs.

```
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
* Restarting with stat
libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394
* Debugger is active!
* Debugger PIN: 347-063-980
```

I have x11Forwarding. The `libdc1394 error` can be ignored. However, I am completely unable to debug why the program hangs. Any ideas? I have pasted `app.py` as well.

```
   import os
  from os import listdir
  from os.path import isfile, join
  from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, render_template, flash, send_from_directory
  from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
  import detector

  UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'static/uploads/'
  PROCESS_FOLDER = 'static/processed/'

  GALLERY_RAW_FOLDER = 'static/gallery/'
  GALLERY_PROC_FOLDER = 'static/gallery/'

  THICK_GALLERY = 'imgThickBlood'
  THIN_GALLERY = 'imgThinBlood'

  STATS_EXTENSION = '.stats'

  ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['jpg','jpeg','png','gif','bmp', 'tif','webp'])
  process_cmd = 'python detect/basic_detector.py '


  app = Flask(__name__)
  app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
  app.config['PROCESS_FOLDER'] = PROCESS_FOLDER
  app.config['GALLERY_RAW_FOLDER'] = GALLERY_RAW_FOLDER
  app.config['GALLERY_PROC_FOLDER'] = GALLERY_PROC_FOLDER
  app.config['THICK_GALLERY'] = THICK_GALLERY
  app.config['THIN_GALLERY'] = THIN_GALLERY
  app.config['STATS_EXTENSION'] = STATS_EXTENSION
  app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024
  app.secret_key = 'my secret malaria key'
  tolerance = 50

  # Index page handler
  @app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
  def index():
     if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
           flash('No file part')
           return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit a empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
           flash('No selected file')
           return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
           filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
           inpath = app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']
           outpath = app.config['PROCESS_FOLDER']
           infile = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
           outfile = os.path.join(app.config['PROCESS_FOLDER'], filename)
           file.save(infile)
           process_file(infile, outfile, str(tolerance))
           return redirect(url_for('view_processed', inpath=inpath, outpath=outpath, filename=filename))
     else:
        # Show thin sample gallery for user to view as an example
        gallery_path = app.config['GALLERY_PROC_FOLDER'] + app.config['THIN_GALLERY'] + 'Input/'
        files = get_files(gallery_path)
        return render_template('index.html', gallery_files=files, upload_path=gallery_path)


  # Show processed file (redirect from index page file upload form)
  @app.route('/view_processed/<filename>')
  def view_processed(filename):
     inpath = app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']
     outpath = app.config['PROCESS_FOLDER']
     red, malaria = get_stats(outpath, filename)
     return render_template('process.html', input_file=inpath, output_file=outpath, filename=filename, red=red, malaria=malaria)


  # Show processed file (redirect from index page gallery)
  @app.route('/mini_gallery/<filename>')
  def mini_gallery(filename):
     inpath = app.config['GALLERY_RAW_FOLDER'] + app.config['THIN_GALLERY'] + 'Input/'
     outpath = app.config['GALLERY_PROC_FOLDER'] + app.config['THIN_GALLERY'] + 'Output/'
     red, malaria = get_stats(outpath, filename)
     return render_template('process.html', input_file=inpath, output_file=outpath, filename=filename, red=red, malaria=malaria)

  # Gallery handler
  @app.route('/gallery', methods=['GET','POST'])
  def gallery():
     if request.method == 'POST':
        threshold = request.form.get('thresholdRadio')
        gallery = request.form.get('galleryRadio')

        if int(threshold) < 0 or int(threshold) > 100:
           return render_template('gallery.html')

        if not 'thin' in gallery and not 'thick' in gallery:
           return render_template('gallery.html')

        if 'thin' in gallery:
           inpath = app.config['GALLERY_RAW_FOLDER'] + app.config['THIN_GALLERY'] + 'Input/'
           outpath = app.config['GALLERY_PROC_FOLDER'] + app.config['THIN_GALLERY'] + 'Output/'
        else:
           inpath = app.config['GALLERY_RAW_FOLDER'] + app.config['THICK_GALLERY'] + 'Input/'
           outpath = app.config['GALLERY_PROC_FOLDER'] + app.config['THICK_GALLERY'] + 'Output/'

        files = get_files(inpath)

        for f in files:
           process_file(inpath+'/'+f, outpath+'/'+f, str(threshold))

        return render_template('gallery.html', gallery_list=files, gallery_inpath=inpath, gallery_outpath=outpath)

     else: 
        inpath = app.config['GALLERY_RAW_FOLDER'] + app.config['THIN_GALLERY'] + 'Input/'
        outpath = app.config['GALLERY_PROC_FOLDER'] + app.config['THIN_GALLERY'] + 'Output/'
        files = get_files(inpath)
        return render_template('gallery.html', gallery_list=files, gallery_inpath=inpath, gallery_outpath=outpath)


  # Gets list of image files excluding .stats files
  def get_files(gallery_path):
     files = [f for f in listdir(gallery_path) if isfile(join(gallery_path, f))]
     files = [f for f in files if allowed_file(f)]
     return files


  # Do malaria detection image processing
  def process_file(inpath, outpath, threshold):   
     detector.process(inpath, outpath, str(threshold))


  # Simple validation of files allowed for upload based on file extension
  def allowed_file(filename):
     return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.',1)[1] in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

  # Get stats about processed image from file
  # Saving stats to file as database not really necessary, and avoiding re-processing to get stats
  def get_stats(outpath, filename):
     statsfile = outpath+'/'+filename+app.config['STATS_EXTENSION']
     red = 0
     malaria = 0
     with open(statsfile, mode='r') as f:
        red = f.readline()
        malaria = f.readline()
     return red, malaria


  if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start the application with your command line but are you then opening up a web browser to that machine on port 5000?

It sounds like you are connecting to that computer remotely so you'll need to modify the app.run() arguments:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

When you run the app.py file again you should see the address change in the print statement:

```
python app.py
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 142-103-744
```

At this point just point a web browser at the machine that is running the Flask WSGI app on port 5000

Example URL for a remote computer running the WSGI app at 192.168.1.15:

```
http://192.168.1.15:5000
```

Comment: Oh i see. How foolish of me! Thank you!